# Extract a key from an object in string format

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary, data-manipulation

How do I extract the `name` key from this string `"[{'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}]"`

I have tried using this re command:

```py
re.findall(r"'name': \D{1,}", text)
```

But it doesnt seem to work

I also tried using `json.loads(text)`
But it gave the error

```py
JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: If you don't want to use `eval` replace the single quotes with double quotes: `json.loads(s.replace("'", '"'))`

Comment: If you have control of how the string is produced, the best course would be to make sure it is a correct JSON in the first place.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Note that this will fail if the string contains either double quotes, or escaped single quotes.

Comment: @Amadan Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
import ast

s = "[{'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}]"

lst = ast.literal_eval(s)
names = [d["name"] for d in lst]
print(names)
```

**Output**

```
['Thriller', 'Drama']
```

As an alternative use the third-party module [`pyyaml`](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation), as below:

```
import yaml

s = "[{'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}]"

lst = yaml.load(s, Loader=yaml.Loader)
names = [d["name"] for d in lst]
print(names)
```

**Output**

```
['Thriller', 'Drama']
```